# An updated approach to testing vuex actions

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, webpack, mocking, vuex

In the ["Testing Actions"](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html#testing-actions) documentation, there is a recommendation to use [inject-loader](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader) in order to mock entire module imports, and their respective dependencies, when unit testing.

For example, you can mock the `../api/shop` import found inside the `./actions` file with the following:

```
const actionsInjector = require('inject-loader!./actions')

// create the module with our mocks
const actions = actionsInjector({
  '../api/shop': {
    getProducts (cb) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb([ /* mocked response */ ])
      }, 100)
    }
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, that package does not support Webpack 5.

Is there an updated approach, or alternative package, that is recommended?

Comment: The docs show the exotic test setup with Mocha for some reason. Use Jest, it already handles module mocking

Comment: I'm actually using vitest, which also has module mocking, the issue I have though is that my first layer of imports, then have their own imports, which have their own imports.

About 3/4 layers down, a few of the dependencies are running their own functinality as the file is imported.

The vitest/Jest mocking only covers the exports, and doesn't prevent modules loading their own import dependencies. Unless I'm missing something in Jest?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that, otherwise mocking would be pretty much useless in Jest. Check https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask).

The clarification/mixup was that, whilst I was using `vi.mock`, and it's auto-mocking algorithm :

> "...will mock the module itself by invoking it and mocking every
> export."

i.e. it still runs the import statements. To prevent this, a factory must be provided ([see documentation](https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#automocking-algorithm)), e.g.:

```
vi.mock('module', <factory-here>)
```

Which then replaces the entire file import.